# Moving from WPF 3.5 to 4.0 causes error "Can't put a page in a Style"

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm in the process of moving my application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0, and I get the following error message : "Can't put a page in a Style".  I've implemented the MVVM pattern for this application and use Data Templates to tell the application how to render my various view models...for example below.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConfigureAxViewModel}">
    <vw:ConfigureAxPage />
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there any way around this error?  Do I have to make my pages controls?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: I'n not surprised this doesn't work in 4.0, I'm confounded that it does in 3.5. Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: What's the misuderstanding?  I defined a datatype as a page.  I saw this in some MVVM tutorial a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Docs for both 3.5 & 4.0:

> A page can be hosted from [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx), [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.aspx), [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx), or from a browser.

I would not expect a view that is a page to work in many instances for that matter, usually views are just `UserControls`. Though i also would not expect that error message...

Answer (score 0):

I happened to get this error in the designer in Visual Studio 2010. A couple of hours later with half of my hair gone, I found the problem in `App.xaml`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
     <views:Login />
</DataTemplate>
```

(So where is the "Style" they talk about???) Anyways, here, Login is a Page. It turns out a Page can't be used here. You have to specify a DataContext in the page's xaml instead:

```
DataContext="{Binding LoginPage,Source={StaticResource Locator}}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812432/2498426)

I'm using MVVM Light so you might want to check it out for more information about the [Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light).