# Dependency Injection with MVVM and Child Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light and I'm currently using SimpleIoC that comes with the package. I'm getting a bit stuck with the dependency injection. I have a bunch of services that I want to use in my view models, however most windows are a List-Edit paradigm, i.e. one screen lists all of type `Person` and then you can Add or Edit a `Person` via a new screen.

When I was doing all code in the code behind my code for adding and editing a record was as follows:

**View**

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.Edit();
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.Add();
}
```

**View Model**

```
public void Add()
{
    var f = new TypeDetails();
    f.Show();
}
public void Edit()
{
   if (SelectedItem == null)
      return;
   var f = new TypeDetails(SelectedItem.Id);
   f.Show();
}
```

The constructor of `TypeDetails` is as follows:

```
public TypeDetails(int id = 0)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new TypeDetailsViewModel(id);
    DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

What would the best be to implement this type functionality with MVVM Light? I have been using the `ViewModelLocator` class for the List screens,  however I cannot see a way to do this using the SimpleIoC. My way round so far has been to keep the constructor the same, which works fine until I need to inject dependencies into the `TypeDetailsViewModel` such as a service. With a service the constructor of `TypeDetailsViewModel` would be:

```
public TypeDetailsViewModel(ISomeService someService, int id = 0)
{
     ...
}
```

But that means in my view constructor I have to build these dependencies one at a time and manually inject them...

```
public TypeDetails(int id = 0)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new TypeDetailsViewModel(SimpleIoC.Current.GetInstance<ISomeService>(),id);
    DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First off I would look into the "RelayCommand" class which is part of MVVM Light. It will remove the need for events in your code behind. Start with that.
- You should always favor "Constructor Injection" instead of the ServiceLocator (ex: SimpleIoC.Current.GetInstance())
- Your ViewModel constructor should only be injecting services and not primitive types like "int". In your example "int id" should be the parameter of a method and not injected.

Ex: Instead, your TypeDetailsViewModel should look more like:

```
public TypeDetailsViewModel(ISomeService someService)
{
     TypeDetail GetDetailsCommand(int id)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

- Lastly, your Models should never have any reference to your ViewModels.
- For your DataContext, you can use a ViewModelLocator ([ViewModels in ViewModelLocator MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light))
- To hook up your View and ViewModel to use the GetDetailsCommand, you can use the EventToCommand behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx). Ex: The OnLoaded event on the View calls the GetDetailsCommand on your ViewModel.

Comment: I have been using RelayCommand, which has eliminated those events, I only had them for examples on how the code used to be. I am curious about where the DataContext is set for the Details screen, should the Ctor of the View call `SimpleIoC` and `GetInstance<T>()`?

With regards to the injection, how would the `GetDetails` method link up to the view in any way? Could you perhaps provide an expanded code sample? I love MVVM but I feel I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Added a couple more details to my answer