# Storing all viewmodels in ViewModelLocator mvvm light

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm-light

Using MVVM Light, Is it ok to store all the viewmodels in viewmodel locator?

```
 public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CoursesViewModel>(true);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<EditCourseViewModel>(true);
            //Many more viewmodels follow
        }
```

Bearing in mind that there will potentially be many ( dozens ) of those alltogether? There is this great 
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light) "ViewModels in ViewModelLocator MVVM Light".

It received a great, detailed answer but the answer didn't actually 'answer' the question, i.e. to quote the author 
**"Should I set DataContext in each page to View Model Property in ViewModelLocator or nest ViewModels as properties in MainVM and bind each page DataContext to Main.PhotosVMProperty, Main.DirectoriesVMProperty and so on?"**

Thank you

Comment: I'm going to reiterate the comments from your linked post: What do you mean, exactly, by 'nest ViewModels as properties in MainVM and bind each page DataContext to Main.PhotosVMProperty, Main.DirectoriesVMProperty and so on'? Can you provide a sample so that a meaningful comparison can be done between the two techniques?