# (WPF/MVVM) Single Instance In MainViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, instance

I have a project that has **3 View/ViewModels** (Until now of course!). So I have a **ListView** in **MainView** to show each one of them, and could be selected by the user. So I used something like this:

```
class MainViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> obv
    {
        get { return this._obv; }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pvm = new PViewModel();
        lvm = new LViewModel();
        svm = new SViewModel();
        cvm = new CViewModel();
        ivm = InstanceViewModel.Instance;
        obv.Add(pvm);
        obv.Add(lvm);
        obv.Add(svm);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And this is the MainView:

```
<Window x:Class="Banking_System.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Banking_System"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Banking_System.View"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Banking_System.Model"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Banking_System.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="1200" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boo2vis"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:PViewModel}">
        <view:P/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:LViewModel}">
        <view:L/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:SViewModel}">
        <view:S/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:CViewModel}">
        <view:C/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMenu" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding obv}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10" Padding="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentControl Margin="10" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBoxMenu}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And then Bind the **ListView** to **obv**. But after doing this, When **SelectedItem** in the ListView changes, This **MainViewModel** gets a new instance And because of that all the other **ViewModels** in it, will get a new instance.(Because I wrote `new *Viewmodel()` in it!)
 *(In another word, all the application get refresh, Like its just got opened!)*

**Q:** So is there anyway to prevent this kind of action?
***Note:*** Although i could use Instances in all the ViewModels and write something like this:

```
/* In each ViewModel have something like this */
public static LViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
                _Instance = new LViewModel();
            return _Instance;
        }      
    }


/* Then change the MainViewModel to something like this */

class MainViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> obv
    {
        get { return this._obv; }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pvm = PViewModel.Instance;
        lvm = LViewModel.Instance;
        svm = SViewModel.Instance;
        cvm = CViewModel.Instance;
        ivm = InstanceViewModel.Instance;
        obv.Add(pvm);
        obv.Add(lvm);
        obv.Add(svm);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

*But I don't if it's right or not!*

**Update:** I don't know about Locator at all! So add another class name **Locator** with this code:

```
class Locator
{
    public LViewModel LInstance
    {
        get { return new LViewModel(); }
    }
    public PViewModel PInstance
    {
        get { return new PViewModel(); }
    }
    public SViewModel SInstance
    {
        get { return new SViewModel(); }
    }
    public MainViewModel MainInstance
    {
        get { return new MainViewModel(); }
    }
}
```

But my **MainViewModel** still as the same as before! I did change my xaml to this:

```
<!--<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>-->
.
.
.
<!-- Just added the DataContext -->
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMenu" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding obv}" DataContext="{Binding MainInstance, Source={StaticResource LocatorVM}}">
.
.
.
```

But still like before, **MainViewModel** and there for other **ViewModels** got reloaded every time!

Comment: 1st, show some xaml please. 2nd, Show some relevant code. That behaviot can noone reproduce with your pasted example

Comment: I think you answered your own question ^ ^

Comment: @lokusking i added the xaml for MainView. Others not important actually! :)

Comment: @ChenChi I know! But don't know if it's alright to do something like this of not!

Comment: It looks ok with me

Comment: @Mostafa I had a MVVM project long time I ago but I think I used the same code in the getter as you

Comment: @ChenChi, Ok then. This is a pretty simple solution, If you say it's alright, I'll use it this way. Thanks!

Comment: All of this excitement! I can hardly contain myself! Amazing! Exclamation point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to either create a "singleton" of your VM's, or you can use a `Locator` like the one that most MVVM frameworks supply. 
(which basically does the same really...).

Let's see if I can link you ...

Well, my my ... what do you know. [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154088/1698987) for more about the locator

Almost. You want something like:

```
class Locator
{
    private LViewModel _lInstance;
    public LViewModel LInstance
    {
        get { return _lInstance ?? (_lInstance = new LInstance()); }
    }
    ....
}
```

This way, you're creating your instance once, and only when requested, and they should survive between changes :)

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't understand exactly how this works, Si I have updated my post if you could take a look at it and tell me what to do!

Comment: So this is just like the one that i wrote in first place? That's called a Locator? :D

Comment: Kinda. here's another take on it : [moah loKator!!](https://johnpapa.net/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum/)

Comment: Now i get it. Works great. Thanks! *Note: Although it doesn't need any **Instance**, And that's the beauty of it.*