# Why is my DashboardView not beeing displayed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Overview:**

I have one `MainWindow` and two `Views`. One representing a Login Screen and the other one is representing the Dashboard. The `LoginView` is shown on `StartUp`. When the User presses the `LoginButton` the `DashboardView` should be shown.

**Here's my Problem:**

The underlying `Command` is beeing executed. The `Constructor` of `DashboardViewModel` is beeing called. And the `View` and `ViewModel` for Dashboard are connected via a `DataTemplate`. But the `View` or the `InitializeComponent` Method are **not** beeing called.

The `LoginCommand` looks like this:

`LoginMainCommands` is a `RelayCommand` Class derived from `ICommand`.

```
public class ButtonViewModel : LoginMainViewModel
{
    public ButtonViewModel()
    {
        _loginCommand = new LoginMainCommands(Login);
    }

    private LoginMainCommands _loginCommand;
    public LoginMainCommands LoginCommand
    {
        get { return _loginCommand; }
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        ViewModelLocator ObjViewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();
        ObjViewModelLocator.MWInstance.SwitchViewModel();
    }
}
```

The connection between the `Views` and the `ViewModels` is in `ManWindow.xaml` as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loginViewModel:LoginMainViewModel}">
        <loginView:LoginMainViewUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dashboardViewModel:DashboardMainViewModel}">
        <dashboardViews:DashboardMainViewUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

To switch between the `Views` I added this Method in `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public void SwitchViewModel()
{
   if (!isLoginView)
   {
      isLoginView = true;
      ViewModel = new LoginMainViewModel();
   }
   else
   {
      isLoginView = false;
      ViewModel = new DashboardMainViewModel();
   }
}
```

**What I've tried so far:**

[I did almost everything this answer suggests.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654812) But I can't connect the `Views` and `ViewModels` in the `App.xaml`, cause then I can't use my `ResourceDictionaries` for Icons and Logos. But they are connected in `MainWindow.xaml`.

Later on I recognized in order for this to work only one `Instance` of `MainWindowViewModel` could exist because otherwise `ViewModel` would be `null` everytime a new `Object` is created. That's why I created `ViewModelLocator` like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39223238).

The weird part for me is when I change the `if` bracket in the `SwitchViewModel` Method to this:

```
if (!isLoginView)
{
   isLoginView = true;
   ViewModel = new DashboardMainViewModel();
}
```

Now `DashboardMainViewModel` is the default `View` to show and it does excatcly that it shows up.

I have no clue why the Dashboard Screen is not beeing shown.

I want to thank everybody in advance for your help and patience!

Comment: Are your both view models really exist in a different namespaces?

Comment: Yes, my two `ViewModels` are in different `Namespaces`. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in the `Login` method in `ButtonViewModel`.

```
ViewModelLocator ObjViewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();
```

In your view model you create a new instance of the `ViewModelLocator`, which in turn creates a **new instance** of `MainWindowViewModel` on which you then call `SwitchViewModel`. That is the **wrong** instance.

You could solve this problem in many different ways, e.g.:

- Make `ViewModelLocator` a [singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton).

  You would set the `DataContext` like this, **without** creating an instance in the `Window.Resources`:

  ```
  DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.Instance}}"
  ```

  Then in `ButtonViewModel` you can directly call the `SwitchViewModel` through `ViewModelLocator`:

  ```
  ViewModelLocator.Instance.MWInstance.SwitchViewModel();
  ```
- Pass a reference of the `MainWindowViewModel` to the other view models

  Passing the instance of `MainWindowViewModel` to the other view models in order to call `SwitchViewModel` works, but makes them tightly coupled and exposes more of the view model than necessary.

  Alternatively, you could create an interface `ISwitchViewModels` with a method `SwitchViewModel` that is implemented by `MainWindowViewModel` and pass it via the interface instead to hide the actual implementation.
- Use events to communicate between view models

  Many WPF MVVM frameworks like [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) or [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/4.0.0/event-aggregator) feature something called an *Event Aggregator* to communicate via events between view models and enable loose coupling. In this case you would not have to depend on a reference from `ButtonViewModel` to `MainWindowViewModel`, instead you would send a message to request changing the current view.
- Use dependency injection to register the `ViewModelLocator` as singleton and pass it to view models

  I guess you are not familiar with dependency injection and it might be beyond the scope of this question, so this is just for further reading.

  Note that in this case the `ViewModelLocator` is not implemented as singleton, but only a single instance of it is created by a container and passed to all other types that specify this dependency.

  [Understanding dependency injection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232229/understanding-dependency-injection)

  [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

> The weird part for me is when I change the if bracket in the SwitchViewModel Method to this: [...]
> Now DashboardMainViewModel is the default View to show and it does excatcly that it shows up.

That is not weird at all, since you directly assign the `ViewModel` property on the right instance of `MainWindowViewModel` without even using the `ViewModelLocator`.