# Does the ViewModelLocator in MVVM light hold instances in memory for every ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I work on a quite big software, with litterly over 100 dialogs. We are considering MVVM light, but I just read an old artikle which states that "All ViewModels are kept im memory till the cleaup is called".
So my questions:

- Does that mean that on load it will load **all** ViewModels in the program?
- If it is the default to load all, can I change it to load/instantiate the ViewModels only when the dialog is opened?

---

The article is [Abkürzung zum ViewModel](http://www.dotnetpro.de/frontend/wpf/abkuerzung-viewmodel-1133161.html). Sorry but it is from 2008, in German and you need to register to read it. But my question is only about that statement, so you may ignore it.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light), it was very informative but I didn't really find an answer to my question.

Comment: No, it does not load all ViewModels in the program

Comment: AFAIK, ViewModels are loaded lazily. But once loaded, they'll stay until cleaned up.

Comment: I think an easy experiment, which takes less than an hour to code, can show this.

Comment: It is open source. Have a look at the sources and you will know whats going on under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default `ViewModelLocator` class created by *nugetting* the `mvvmlight` package.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        ////{
        ////    // Create design time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Create run time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        ////}

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

There is no magic creating any viewmodel inside that class unless **you** put it in there. By default there is a `ServiceLocator` involved, which you can remove and replace by any DI container of your choice or do the instantiation of the ViewModels handled by this `ViewModelLocator` manually.

The `static Cleanup()` is **not called** by default and you have to place the call whereever you like to get it called whenever you like. That is all up to you if that is needed at all.

**Conclusion**: It is all up to you how the `ViewModelLocator` will operate and behave

To answer your questions:

> - Does that mean that on load it will load **all** ViewModels in the program?

Nope, unless you write code that will do so

> - If it is the default to load all, can I change it to load/instantiate the ViewModels only when the dialog is opened?

(see above)

Comment: Hm, but using SimpleIoc Containers in there, Viewmodels will be created lazy, right? At least I thought so.

Comment: Did a quick research myself: There is [void Register<TInterface, TClass>( bool createInstanceImmediately )](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/a1995dc0-d1ba-4b80-553d-a3401bbc1f65.htm) with which you can force immediate creation. So I guess the default is lazy (the docs don't explicitly state that, as far as I read).

Comment: As I said: You can create the instances manually or delegated to any DI container of your choice => everything is under your control

Comment: There is no rule when to call that method. I guess in most cases it will never be called. So never mind about it, unless you face a situation where such method would be handy.