# Page navigation in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using a NavigationWindow to house my pages in this WPF application. I am just learning MVVM with WPF and have been looking for a good solution to navigating pages while maintaining MVVM.

I have a LoginViewModel that does all SQL database credential checking, once the credentials have been verified against a Password Hash I want to navigate to a new page depending on who logs in.

I am looking for some suggestions or common answers to this solution. I have done a lot of research and keep seeing IOC containers or an application view model? I wanted to get some other opinions on the matter and possibly a point in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a framework to achieve the IOC container solution. Mvvm light for example uses a [ViewModelLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light)  to store its ViewModels.
An example for page navigation in MVVMLight can be found [here](http://www.joeljoseph.net/navigation-between-pages-using-mvvm-light-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp/).