# Navigation with MVVM template WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm planning wpf `MVVM` application. I read a lot of about `MVVM` pattern. But I can't find best practices to implement navigation.

I have scenario application starts with login screen and after login i want to have page with navigation menu. How should I handle that?

I read about use `Frame`, `UserControl` and `viewModel` container. But It's not clear to me what should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are 100000 options how to implement navigation

- Using [DataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Create DataTemplates in your resources

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YOUR_PAGE_VIEWMODEL1}">
   <local:YOUR_PAGE1/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YOUR_PAGE_VIEWMODEL2}">
   <local:YOUR_PAGE2/>
</DataTemplate>
```

NOTE: YOUR_PAGE_VIEWMODEL1 and YOUR_PAGE_VIEWMODEL2 have the same base class in our case (lets call it **BasePageViewModel**)

then in your MainViewModel you can add something like this

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //....
  public BasePageViewModel CurrentPage { get; set; } //don't forget to notify
  //....
}
```

And finaly you can bind your CurrentPage to your Frame

```
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

- Using [MVVMC](https://michaelscodingspot.com/wpf-page-navigation-like-mvc-building-mvvm-framework-controllers/)
- Using a [Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130327/viewmodels-in-viewmodellocator-mvvm-light)